# JSF bean can not get attributes from f:attribute (NullPointerException)

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get two page attributes in two validator beans using getAttributes() but the function can not get them having as a result a NullPointerException. Using exactly the same code from another page and another validator I didn't had any problem getting them. I am using JSF 2.2 with Apache 7 on Windows XP 32bit.

The code that doensn't work:

addEmployee.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">
                #{msg.addEmployee}
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="body">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    PrimeFaces.locales['el'] = {
                        closeText: 'Κλείσιμο',
                        prevText: 'Προηγούμενο',
                        nextText: 'Επόμενο',
                        monthNames: ['Ιανουάριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μάρτιος', 'Απρίλιος', 'Μάϊος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Άυγουστος', 'Σεπτέμβιος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος', 'Δεκέμβριος'],
                        monthNamesShort: ['Ιαν', 'Φεβ', 'Μαρ', 'Απρ', 'Μαι', 'Ιουν', 'Ιουλ', 'Αυγ', 'Σεπ', 'Οκτ', 'Νοε', 'Δεκ'],
                        dayNames: ['Κυριακή', 'Δευτέρα', 'Τρίτη', 'Τετάρτη', 'Πέμπτη', 'Παρασκευή', 'Σάββατο'],
                        dayNamesShort: ['Κυρ', 'Δευ', 'Τρι', 'Τετ', 'Πεμ', 'Παρ', 'Σαβ'],
                        dayNamesMin: ['Κ', 'Δ', 'Τρ', 'Τε', 'Πε', 'Πα', 'Σ'],
                        weekHeader: 'Εβδ',
                        firstDay: 1,
                        isRTL: false,
                        showMonthAfterYear: false,
                        yearSuffix: '',
                        timeOnlyTitle: 'Επιλογή Ώρας',
                        timeText: 'Χρόνος',
                        hourText: 'Ώρα',
                        minuteText: 'Λεπτό',
                        secondText: 'Δεύτερολεπτο',
                        currentText: 'Τώρα',
                        ampm: false,
                        month: 'Μήνας',
                        week: 'Εβδομάδα',
                        day: 'Μέρα',
                        allDayText: 'Όλη Μέρα'
                    };
                </script>  
                <h:form id="addEmployeePanel" prependId="false">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="10000"/>  
                    <table align="center" boarder="0">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <p:outputPanel>
                                    <p:panel id="basicInfoPanel">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            #{msg.basicInfo}
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                                            <h:outputLabel for="surnameInput" value="#{msg.surname}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.surname}" id="surnameInput" required="true" label="surname" requiredMessage="#{msg.surnameRequired}" maxlength="128" size="32">
                                                <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexSurnameError}" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="nameInput" value="#{msg.name}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.name}" id="nameInput" required="true" label="name" requiredMessage="#{msg.nameRequired}" maxlength="128" size="32">
                                                <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexΝameError}" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="fathersNameInput" value="#{msg.fathersName}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.fathersName}" id="fathersNameInput" required="true" label="fathersName" requiredMessage="#{msg.fathersNameRequired}" maxlength="128" size="32">
                                                <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexFathersΝameError}" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="mothersNameInput" value="#{msg.mothersName}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.mothersName}" id="mothersNameInput" required="true" label="mothersName" requiredMessage="#{msg.mothersNameRequired}" maxlength="128" size="32">
                                                <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexMothersΝameError}" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="birthDateCalendar" value="#{msg.birthDate}:" /> 
                                            <p:calendar value="#{addEmployee.surname}" id="birthDateCalendar" required="true" label="birthDate" requiredMessage="#{msg.birthDateRequired}" validatorMessage="#{msg.regexBirthDateError}" showOn="button" locale="el" size="32">
                                            </p:calendar>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="identityNumberInput" value="#{msg.identityNumber}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.identityNumber}" id="identityNumberInput" required="true" label="identityNumber" requiredMessage="#{msg.identityNumber}" maxlength="12" size="32">
                                                <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ω0-9\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexIdentityNumberError}" />
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="afmShortInput" value="#{msg.afmShort}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.afm}" id="afmShortInput" required="true" label="afmShortInput" requiredMessage="#{msg.afmShortRequired}" maxlength="9" size="32">
                                                <f:validator validatorId="afmValidator" />
                                                <f:attribute name="afm" value="#{afmShortInput}"/>
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="amkaShortInput" value="#{msg.amkaShort}:" /> 
                                            <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.amka}" id="amkaShortInput" required="true" label="amkaShortInput" requiredMessage="#{msg.amkaShortRequired}" maxlength="128" size="32">
                                                <f:validator validatorId="amkaValidator" />
                                                <f:attribute name="amka" value="#{amkaShortInput}"/>
                                            </p:inputText>
                                            <h:outputLabel for="attributeMenu" value="#{msg.attribute}:" /> 
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="attributeMenu" value="#{addEmployee.selectedAttribute}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.attributeRequired}" style="width:305px">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.select}" itemValue=""/>
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{addEmployee.attribute}"/>
                                                <p:ajax update="containerPanel, infoOutputPanel, extraInfoPanel, rankMenu, educationTypeMenu" listener="#{addEmployee.updateAttributeSelected}" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                    </p:panel>
                                    <p:blockUI block="basicInfoPanel" trigger="add">  
                                        <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax_loader.gif" height="64" width="64"/>  
                                    </p:blockUI>
                                </p:outputPanel>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <h:panelGroup id="containerPanel" layout="block">
                                    <p:outputPanel id="infoOutputPanel" rendered="#{addEmployee.infoOutputPanelRendered}" autoUpdate="true">
                                        <p:effect type="slide" event="load"/> 

                                        <p:panel id="extraInfoPanel">
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                                #{msg.extraInfo}
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">                                         
                                                <h:outputLabel for="idInput" value="#{msg.id}:"/> 
                                                <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.id}" id="idInput" required="true" label="id" requiredMessage="#{msg.idRequired}" maxlength="32"  size="32">
                                                    <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[α-ωΑ-Ωa-zA-Z0-9\s]*$" message="#{msg.regexIdError}" />
                                                </p:inputText>
                                                <h:outputLabel for="rankMenu" value="#{msg.rank}:"/> 
                                                <p:selectOneMenu id="rankMenu" value="#{addEmployee.selectedRank}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.rankRequired}" style="width:305px">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.select}" itemValue=""/>
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{addEmployee.rank}"/>
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                                <h:outputLabel for="socialSecurityMenu" value="#{msg.socialSecurity}:"/> 
                                                <p:selectOneMenu id="socialSecurityMenu" value="#{addEmployee.selectedSocialSecurity}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.socialSecurityRequired}" style="width:305px">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.select}" itemValue=""/>
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{addEmployee.socialSecurity}"/>
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                                <h:outputLabel for="educationTypeMenu" value="#{msg.educationType}:"/> 
                                                <p:selectOneMenu id="educationTypeMenu" value="#{addEmployee.selectedDegree}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.educationTypeRequired}" style="width:305px" disabled="#{addEmployee.degreeDisabled}">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.select}" itemValue=""/>
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{addEmployee.degree}"/>
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                                <h:outputLabel for="ibanInput" value="#{msg.iban}:"/> 
                                                <p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.iban}" id="ibanInput" required="true" label="iban" requiredMessage="#{msg.ibanRequired}" maxlength="27"  size="32">
                                                    <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[GR]{2}[0-9]{25}$" message="#{msg.regexIbanError}" />
                                                </p:inputText>
                                                <f:facet name="footer">  
                                                    <p:commandButton id="add" value="#{msg.add}" update="messages" action="#{loginMgmtBean.login}"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                            </h:panelGrid>                                            
                                        </p:panel>
                                        <p:blockUI block="extraInfoPanel" trigger="add">  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax_loader.gif" height="64" width="64"/>  
                                        </p:blockUI> 
                                    </p:outputPanel>                                   
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

AfmValidator

```
package extra.validators;

import extra.dao.DBConnection;
import extra.logger.DBLogger;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import static org.omnifaces.util.Faces.getRemoteAddr;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@FacesValidator("afmValidator")
public class AfmValidator implements Validator {

    //Η αποδεκτή μορφή (χαρακτήρες) για το όνομα χρήστη
    private static final String AFM_PATTERN = "(^[0-9]{9})$";
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public AfmValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(AFM_PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        con = DBConnection.getInstance().openConnection();
        //Φόρτωση του ΑΦΜ από την σελίδα που τον κάλεσε
        UIInput uiInputAfm = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("afm");
        String afm = uiInputAfm.getSubmittedValue().toString();
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                //Έλεγχος για το αν το ΑΦΜ είναι σωστό
                matcher = pattern.matcher(afm);
                if (!matcher.matches()) {
                    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Αποτυχία προσθήκης", "Ο Α.Φ.Μ. μπορεί να αποτελείται μόνο από αριθμούς"));
                } else {
                    //Έλεγχος για τον αν υπάρχει ήδη ο εργαζόμενος
                    String select = "SELECT VAL FROM EMP WHERE VAL = ? AND PARAM_CD = 'AFM'";
                    pst = con.prepareStatement(select);
                    pst.setString(1, afm);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Αποτυχία προσθήκης", "Ο εργαζόμενος υπάρχει ήδη"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                DBLogger.addLog(afm, getRemoteAddr(), "AfmValidator.validate", "trying to validate afm", ex.toString());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                RequestContext errorContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                errorContext.addCallbackParam("added", false);
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Αποτυχία προσθήκης", "Προέκυψε σφάλμα κατά την προσπάθεια προσθήκης νέου εργαζόμενου. Αν το πρόβλημα εμφανιστεί ξανά, παρακαλώ επικοινωνήστε με τον διαχειριστή του συστήματος"));
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if (pst != null) {
                        pst.close();
                    }
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    DBLogger.addLog(afm, getRemoteAddr(), "AfmValidator.validate", "trying to close the resultset/preparedstatement/connection", ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            DBLogger.addLog(afm, getRemoteAddr(), "AfmValidator.validate", "could not open the connection");
            RequestContext errorContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            errorContext.addCallbackParam("added", false);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Αποτυχία προσθήκης", "Προέκυψε σφάλμα κατά την προσπάθεια προσθήκης νέου εργαζόμενου. Αν το πρόβλημα εμφανιστεί ξανά, παρακαλώ επικοινωνήστε με τον διαχειριστή του συστήματος"));
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIInput
    at army.olkes.extra.validators.AfmValidator.validate(AfmValidator.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: The way you are trying to get attribute is wrong. It should be String afmShortInput = (String)component.getAttributes().get("afmShortInput"); and you can remove String afm = uiInputAfm.getSubmittedValue().toString(); statement which is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: ALWAYS include the trace if you're given an Exception. That way, answerers can infer what's going on. BTW why don't you try just going with debugger to see what's the `null` reference?

Comment: I know the null reference. The component.getAttributes().get("afmShortInput") returns null. And this is why I can not use Srikanth's advice.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to send as a value in the following statement <f:attribute name="afmShortInput" value="#{afmShortInput}"/>. Because afmShortInput is used as an id and label. Its not a variable or holding any value.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji sorry, my mistake. I forgot to return it to its original state after experimenting a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that I had forgot the "binding" property of the inputText and so it became:

```
<h:outputLabel for="afmShortInput" value="#{msg.afmShort}:" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.afm}"
                id="afmShortInput"
          required="true"
             label="afmShortInput"
   requiredMessage="#{msg.afmShortRequired}"
           binding="#{afm}"
         maxlength="9"
              size="32">
  <f:validator validatorId="afmValidator" />
  <f:attribute name="afm" value="#{afm}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: I couldn't guess a reason why exactly you want to use binding and send it as an attribute when you have same component instance being sent as a method parameter to validate method. Use downcasting from UIComponent to UIInput as McDowell suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant view code:

```
<h:outputLabel for="afmShortInput" value="#{msg.afmShort}:" /> 
<p:inputText value="#{addEmployee.afm}"
                id="afmShortInput"
          required="true"
             label="afmShortInput"
   requiredMessage="#{msg.afmShortRequired}"
         maxlength="9"
              size="32">
  <f:validator validatorId="afmValidator" />
  <f:attribute name="afm" value="#{afmShortInput}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Validator code:

```
UIInput uiInputAfm = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("afm");
```

The expression `#{afmShortInput}` will not resolve to the *UIInput* instance as individual UI tree elements are not automatically bound to any scope. It is possible to inject components into a scope but binding a control to one of its own attributes seems unwise. You already have a reference to the component in the validator. Use:

```
UIInput uiInputAfm = (UIInput) component;
```

Comment: Thank you @McDowell for the answer. Even though I finally found the solution, can you please explain some more what you are saying in you answer?

Comment: You essentially have `uiInputAfm == uiInputAfm.getAttributes().get("afm)`. If you need references to multiple components, use a request scoped [managed bean validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-page-core004.htm#BNATN) instead of a named validator and bind the components to that.

Comment: Here is an article covering this: http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2011/10/parametrizing-custom-validator-jsf-2/, no binding required.